# How to pass datetime parameter to HTTP GET message

Tags: angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass two Datetime Parameter from form to WEB API from Angular JS but could not make it work. However I am able to pass only date without time to WEB API Method.

My form DateTime controls looks like below:-

[image]

Now I want to pass Datetime like below from Angular JS:-

**Angular JS Call**

```
        var startTime = $filter('date')($scope.md_invstarttime, "HH:mm");
        startTime = startTime.split(':');
        var invStartDate = new Date($scope.md_invstart);
        invStartDate.setHours(startTime[0]);
        invStartDate.setMinutes(startTime[1]);

        var invBookDate = $filter('date')(invStartDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000")

        var endTime = $filter('date')($scope.md_invendtime, "HH:mm");
        endTime = endTime.split(':');
        var invEndDate = new Date($scope.md_invend);
        invEndDate.setHours(endTime[0]);
        invEndDate.setMinutes(endTime[1]);

        var invBookEndDate = $filter('date')(invEndDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000")

        MetadataOrgFactory.getTriIdApiCall('checkinvavail', invBookDate, invBookEndDate, $scope.md_invid,       
            function (dataSuccess) {                
            }, function (dataError) {
        });
```

**Controller Method**

```
 [Authorize]
        [Route("api/checkinvavail/{invstarttime}/{invendtime}/{invid}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public bool GetInvAvailability(DateTime invstarttime, DateTime invendtime,Guid invid)
        {
            InventoryBLL checkInv = new InventoryBLL();
            bool isAvailable = checkInv.IsAvailable(invstarttime, invendtime,invid)
            return isAvailable;
        }
```

I have searched many articles but none could solve my problem and hence this post. It would be really helpful if any one post the exact solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date object into timestamp by `var timestamp = datevar * 1` then pass the timestamp instead. Then in the backend convert the timestamp back to date object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
var invBookEndDate = $filter('date')(invEndDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000")
```

at Front end convert it to timestamp.

```
invBookEndDate = invEndDate.getTime()
```

At the backend,convert it back to Date object with appropriate timezone you want.